# PHP: file_get_contents(compress.zlib://php://input): failed to open stream: operation failed

Tags: php, gzip, zlib, lighttpd

After upgrading to PHP5.6 the following doesn't work anymore:

```
$json = file_get_contents('compress.zlib://php://input');
```

For this line I get the following error message:

> file_get_contents(compress.zlib://php://input): failed to open stream: operation failed

What is wrong here? I need to decompress the received content, because my client sends a gzip compressed content to the server. A ssl connection is used, but shouldn't be a problem, because the http server (lighttpd) should already decrypt the content (at least it was working in a previous version).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this writing you must be using an RC version of PHP 5.6 which is a bugfix-only release candidate. If you feel this is a true bug in PHP 5.6 I recommend you submit a bug report. http://www.php.net/archive/2014.php#id2014-07-03-1